# How to set the chart minimum scale to specific values

Tags: excel, charts, scale, vba

How to set the minimum scale to a specific cell value, where in the cell is not constant.
ie: if the minimum scale has to be set to 45, and if the value 45 doesn't always occur in the cell `D14`?

`.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = 45 ' Constant value`

Comment: Do you want to set the minimum scale to the lowest value in the range, say `D1:D20`?

Comment: actually it has to be configurable, yes range can be between D1:D30

Comment: Like this? `.MinimumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("D1:D30"))`

Comment: no, i just want to set the minimum scale to a cell value, it can be 30 or 45, and these values may occur between the range D1:D30

Comment: That is what the above does :)

Comment: i just have to add this line to the line specified in the question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13013/discussion-between-user1270123-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: Replace `45` with `Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("D1:D30"))` and it will ok :)

Comment: it is actually taking default values.like starting from 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the minimum scale to the lowest value in the range, use the `MIN` function. Now since the range in not in the workbook which has the chart but in the csv file which you are opening, you have to fully qualify the range

To do that, declare a range object and then set it to the relevant range

```
Dim Rng As Range

'
'~~> Rest of your code
'
Set wsTemp = wbTemp.Sheets(1)
Set Rng = wsTemp.Range("D3:D30")

'
'~~> Rest of your code
'
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Rng)
```

HTH